# New deep cycle batteries produce low capacity and strange voltage behaviour

Tags: batteries, lead-acid

Batteries: Royal 1150k 105ah(20h)
Reserve capacity 180min(25A)

Inverter Load :27.5amp(constant)..measured.

My battery is lasting 30mins on this load.

When starting discharge from full it quickly drops to around 12.2v, then continues downward slower as the amp requirements go up to attain the desired watts output the battery drops faster and dies at around 30mins...leaving the battery after discharge disconnected the voltage recovers back to 12.8v-13v...

Please help if you can, I do not understand why its doing this... the built in hydrometer never goes off green.

Thnx in advance

Comment: What's the battery voltage when it "dies"?

Comment: `105ah(20h)` means 5 A draw for 20 hours ... higher currents will reduce the discharge time ... refer to the battery datasheet

Comment: Dies at 7v...then shoots back up to nearly full and higher than full

Comment: @jsotala 180min reserve capacity means it can deliver 25 amps for 3 hours..30min is way too fast

Answer (score 0):

When you discharge a battery quickly you create depletion zones on the plates (I am assuming this is a lead acid battery, since you mentioned deep cycle) So the battery will appear mostly dead or at least below a useable value.  If stop using the remaining charge will equalize on the plates.  The unloaded voltage will go closer to the starting voltage.  But will only have limited capacity and will discharge it even deeper if you attempt to use.  Knowing your voltage draw a current you could calculate roughly how much charge you have left. But it is effectively dead and needs recharging.

Comment: The reserve capacity states 180min...could there be damage causing the quick discharge